# Python TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Need help. 
Have a list of data named arglist, example:
['dlink', 'des', '1210', 'c', 24] <-- this what "print" views.

And this code:

```
sw_info ={"Brand":arglist[0],
        "Model":arglist[1],
        "Hardware":arglist[2],
        "Software":arglist[3],
        "Portsnum":arglist[4]}


print json.dumps(sw_info, open("test", "w"))
z = json.loads(open("test", "r"))
print s
```

It gives:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parsetest.py", line 34, in <module>
    z = json.loads(open("test", "r"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/decoder.py", line 335, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: You're trying to `loads` a file object, not a string. You should just use `json.load` and `json.dump` if you want to work with files instead of strings.

Comment: First rule of debugging is to assume the error is telling you the literal truth. It's expecting a string but you're not giving it one. So start your investigation with why you're passing something that's not a string or why you're using a function that requires a string when you have something else.

Comment: You right. So obvious. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You are trying to load a file object, when json.loads expects a string. You could either use

```
z = json.loads(open("test", "r").read())
```

or, much better:

```
with open("test") as f:
    z = json.load(f)
```

In the first example, the file is opened, but never closed (bad practice). In the second example, the context manager closes the file after leaving the context block.

Comment: `.read()` is important here. The `open` build-in returns a file object, not a string.

Comment: To clarify: json.loads(open(...).read()) works, and json.load(open(...)) also works. `loads` with an `s` requires a string, `load` without `s` takes a file. `.read()` turns a file into a string.

Comment: @Jonathan No, that would be `loads`. `load` expects a file-like object.