# Reading long buffer into json.load() in Python

Tags: python, json, buffer

I am trying to load a buffer (length of 2260 chars) into a Python object, using the `json` package.

The body comes from a rabbitmq message:

```
def process_message(body, message):
    print("The body is {}".format(body))
    body_as_string = ""
    for char in body:
        body_as_string += char
    json_loaded_obj = json.loads(body_as_string)

...

def handle(self, *args, **options):
        new_conn = Connection(RABBIT_URL, heartbeat=10)
        exchange = Exchange(EXCHANGE_NAME, type="direct")
        queue = Queue(name=QUEUE_NAME, exchange=exchange, routing_key=ROUTING_KEY)
        consumer = Consumer(new_conn, queues=queue, callbacks=[process_message], accept=["text/plain"])
```

I have tried a few things, recently:

```
ipdb> body
<read-only buffer ptr 0x2988c07, size 2260 at 0x7f56c4ee8930>
ipdb> with open(body) as dadbod: conversion = json.load(dadbod)
*** IOError: [Errno 36] File name too long: <read-only buffer ptr 0x2988c07, size 2260 at 0x7f56c4ee8930>
```

Loading the buffer as a file object failed too, it doesn't behave like a file I guess:

[Python TypeError: expected string or buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33336160/python-typeerror-expected-string-or-buffer)

This `json.decoder` answer that came up didn't work when I tried, it seemed a different problem than I have.

I just want to take the buffer and turn its JSON into a Python object. This works:

```
body_as_string = ""
  for char in body:
      body_as_string += char
```

But, it is ugly and this test is serious, I want a clean solution. I'd prefer to learn how to use `json.JSONDecoder()` or whatever proper package should be used if possible.

Comment: How did you build the `body` object ? You should wrap it in a file like object (opened for read) and use this wrapped object in `json.load(wrapped_body)`.

Comment: oh ya the body comes in from rabbitmq

Comment: I mean the code that creates this `body` object. I guess your code has somewhere a `body = some_api(param, param, ...)`. Try in ipdb `help(body)`, `dir(body)`, `type(body)` to get more hints.